# Mono<Void>.flatMap is not getting invoked when it returns Mono<Something>

Tags: java, file-upload, spring-webflux

I'm new to WebFlux. Developing file upload API. I want to save the uploaded file and meta to db and return the saved entity as a response. The lambda expression is not getting invoked in `flatMap` on `filePart.transferTo`. I feel using the `block()` would make using WebFlux pointless. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
public Mono<Music> uploadMusic(FilePart filePart) throws IOException {
    File file = File.createTempFile("tmp-", filePart.filename());
    file.deleteOnExit();
    Music music = new Music();
    return filePart.transferTo(file).flatMap((it) -> {
        music.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
        music.setMeta(new Metadata());
        log.info(String.valueOf(music));
        return this.musicRepository.save(music);
    });
}
```

When I did snippet test I found that `Mono<Void>`.flatMap returning `Mono<SomeObj>` is seems to be the problem.

```
// Lambda expression not invoked
public Mono<Music> voidToObj(FilePart filePart) throws IOException {
    Music music = new Music();
    return Mono.just(music).then().flatMap(it -> {
        music.setMeta(new Metadata());
        log.info(music.toString());
        return Mono.just(music);
    });
}

// Lambda expression invoked
public Mono<Music> objToObj(FilePart filePart) throws IOException {
    Music music = new Music();
    return Mono.just(music).flatMap(it -> {
        music.setMeta(new Metadata());
        log.info(music.toString());
        return Mono.just(music);
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, "flat mapping" a `Mono<Void>` is useless .. (it normally completes immediately without "elements") but "getting complete/error signals" from it is ok (`then(...)`)

Comment: so e.g. `return filePart.transferTo(file).and(updateMusic(music)).then(musicRepository.save(music));`  (updateMusic:Mono<Void>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mono<Void>` doesn't produce a value because Void is [not an object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Void.html). Basically it's the same as an empty Mono, it just completes without any actual element.

As per docs https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

> Mono<Void> should be used for Publisher that just completes without any value.

So a `flatMap`, as well as any other method that is supposed to process a value, would never be called after `Mono.just(music).then().flatMap`.

But if you just want to update and return the value you already have then you can do:

```
return filePart.transferTo(file).then(Mono.defer(() -> {
    music.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    music.setMeta(new Metadata());
    log.info(String.valueOf(music));
    // assuming .save returns a publisher
    return this.musicRepository.save(music);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, it workd. Just wanted to make sure that using `then` or `Mono.defer` will it make the process from async to sync?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _from async to sync_ in this case, but I can tell you that this code gets executed after the file transfer is completed.